# Is it possible in Google Map Drawing a circle and check which coordinates falls on the circle?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a big map in my site and I have implemented enabling drawing of shapes (like circle, rectangles) on it by the Google Maps API v3.

I have a set of locations (consisting of coordinates). Is there a way that I can check which of the coordinated falls on the shape (say circle) user have drawn on the map?

I have checked several questions here and searched on Google but couldn't find a specific way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: I am sure there is. When you can map the radius of the circle to the difference in lattitude and longitude between center point and the points of the circle, you should be able to create a formula to calculate if coordinates fall within that circle. The exact formula for a circle I would not know.Rectangles should be easier, so you could start with that. If you seek the exact formulaes to get it to work, I cannot help you, but this may help you on the way a bit.

Comment: The number of coordinates, (points), within any given polygon, (circle or otherwise), is infinite.

Comment: @DanielVanDommele, Thanks for the answer. I am sure it is possible too. But the problem is after drawing the circle it is unclear that which are the properties of the circle object to be accessed for the purpose. That is why I asked. I do have the formula of the circle too. But as Marcelo talked in your following comment the number of coordinates in any given polygon are infinite.

Comment: @Marcelo, Yes I agree. But there should be some ways so that I can cal any property of the circle object to compare if any of my given point is within the infinite points or not. You got me, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you need to calculate the distance from the center to the coordinates that you need. Then you check if the distance it's equal to the radius of your circle.

Compare. The distance  between the center and the other coordinates it could be calculated with the `levenshtein` or you can use the `getDistanceMatrix` using the library places.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the shape.

1. for a circle use the [spherical geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) computeDistanceBetween() method, for each point and the center of the circle (if the computed distance is less than the radius of the circle, the point is inside)
2. for a rectangle use [LatLngBounds.contains()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)
3. for a polygon use the [poly library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) containsLocation() method.